# Cannot convert datagridview to xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

This is my code: 
I import excel file which I create to datagridvies and wanted to create 'universal' code who convert datagridview to xml. but I have two problems: first I want, when I export, to have xml file which contains names of columns (name, surname...) as a tag instead of 'Column 1, Column 2...', and second: my savebox dialog constantly repeat open after save, again and again. 
First i created method for exporting xml, and in method button4_Click I called that exportXML method.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exportXML("biblioteka");
} // button4 click event

private void exportXML(string fileName) /*this is export xml function*/            {
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        foreach(var column in dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
        var cellValues = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

        foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<row.Cells.Count;i++)
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        /* string fileName = "Biblioteka.XML";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
        ds.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Close();*/

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                if(value == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in read file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.FileName = fileName;
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xml";

                    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // pretvaranje fajla u xml fajl
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
                            ds.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
                            xmlWriter.Flush();
                            xmlWriter.Close();
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception exception)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString()); 
         throw;
     }
}
```

Comment: If you create a datatable initially and make the datatable the datasource (dataGidView1.DataSource = dt) then all you have to do is save the datatable as Xml instead converting the DGV to a DataTable.

Comment: _"my savebox dialog constantly repeat open after save, again and again"_ - that's because you're calling it for every cell!

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I created one excel file, And I import that excel file into datagridview, and wanted to export that data from datagridview to new xml file. I slowed for dialog box repeat. but I don't know how to do first question :D